# Search for tags a user has

Tags: feature-request

Bob wants to view Jon Skeet's acquired score under some tag. He soon realized it's impossible, his computer will collapse into a blackhole before the whole page loads

[image: Jon Skeet's tags]

And also because he doesn't have a search box.

Can we have a search box for tags?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: @HansPassant Sure... it's just not all that nice a UX. Plus sometimes a tag doesn't start with the word you care about (eg mysql). And also skipping past page 5 requires you to type it in the address bar

Answer (score 5):

You can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/857038?tagname=.net&UserId=22656) to get an guesstimation

```sql
select tagname
     , count(*) as [Number of posts]
     , sum(case when posttypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end ) as [# Answers]
     , sum(p.score) as [Total Score]
     , sum(case when CommunityOwnedDate is null and p.posttypeid = 2 then p.score else 0 end) as [Non wiki answer score]
     , sum(case when CommunityOwnedDate is not null and p.posttypeid = 2 then p.score else 0 end) as [Wiki answer score]
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where p.owneruserid = ##userid:int?22656##
and tagname = ##tagname:string?.net##
group by tagname
```

When run today for the .net tag you'll find:

[image: jon skeet .net tag score]

which is close enough ...

> 5435 posts in the .net tag, Asked 8 non-wiki questions with a total score of 713. Gave 5399 non-wiki answers with a total score of 70218.

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week on Sunday. If you want to give SEDE a try yourself, the [awesome tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) is a good starting point.